# MS SQL 2008 Job Fails

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I created an SSIS package to export a flat file based on a query using the Import/Export wizard.  I used Windows Authentication for everything and have the flat file saved to a different server on the network.  When I click Finish, it runs the query and the file is created, no problem.

Now, If I create a Job and schedule it to run at a specific time, it fails.  It has something to do with the file path on the destination server.  If I change it to the local C: drive on the database server, the job runs fine.

I noticed in the Job setup window, the only option to run the SSIS package is as "SQL Server Agent Service Account".  I suppose this user does not have privileges to write to a network server?  Like I said, the SSIS package runs fine - its when I try and run it as a scheduled job that it fails.  The error message is that the destination file name is invalid.

Comment: Does your server set up to handle UNC paths?  That is, paths from one server to another.

Comment: Also, does your server (and the service account under which it runs) have access rights on the destination folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/131931/sql-server-2005-agent-running-ssis-job-cant-find-file-path

Comment: Why is this "off topic"?  I read the FAQ and it doesn't seem to be off topic.  It's specifically a programming question dealing with permissions.  Not to mention the "duplicate" that's not closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem. You're right, it's a permissions issue despite the error message. When you run it manually, it's running under your account, but when the Job runs it, it's the account under which the SQL Agent Windows Service runs that's trying to write the file. So you need to make sure the SQL Agent account has access to the folder.

Just right click the folder, choose permissions and either give read/write access to "Everyone" or to be more safe give Read/Write permissions to the same account that the SQL Agent Windows Service runs under.

Comment: Thanks.  It's what I suspected.